# How does Apple Watch get a phone call?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I switched from AT&T to T-Mobile, and I had an Apple Watch before that.  Never told either one about the watch.  Yesterday, the iPhone shut down (battery) during a call, and the guy immediately called me back on the watch.

But when T-mobile recently sold us a newer Apple watch (for my wife), they added ten dollars a month to the bill for service.  And the new watch has its own phone number.

**How does the Watch receive a phone call when the phone it's paired with is unavailable?**  Is T-Mobile conning us charging ten dollars a month for functions we would have had anyway?

Comment: Looks like it might; there's a lot there.  Will take some study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re paying for cellular service the carrier rings both the phone and your watch on the phone number ([carriers issue a separate billing number to the watch but it dials in and out with the same number as the phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/298374/5472)).

If you have WiFi calling enabled the call will also attempt to be placed over SIP via WiFi.

The only way to know for sure which happened is to disable the other path. (No cellular network or no WiFi network or disable the watch as a WiFi destination).

Comment: But the older watch was never listed on the T-Mobile bill (nor AT&T) and still isn't.  But the new one is listed with a phone number and a ten-dollar charge each month.  So, it seems that pairing it to the phone made it work and probably would have made the new one work without the extra charges.

Comment: WiFi calling works without any carrier involvement on the watch, Mac, iPad. You just need WiFi and an iCloud account. @WGroleau

Comment: OK, that explains why I never get a Watch call when away from home without my phone.